# Where is the code that creates a unit test database in Django?

Tags: django

For unit testing, Django creates a test database, runs unit tests, then destroys that database.  Where is the code that does that?

I looked in github, and couldn't find anything.

For example, at the beginning of unit testing, I see this message:

> Creating test database for alias 'default'...

but when I [look in github for "Creating test database for alias"](https://github.com/django/django/search?q=Creating%20test%20database%20for%20alias), I find nothing.

Related: how does the testing code connect to that database, given that it's not specified in the DATABASES settings? (That is, "default" is in settings, but the test database "test_default" is not.) Or, where is the code that connects to the test database?

Answer (score 2):

For Django around 4.1, I believe

- the literal line that produces the "Creating" message from the question is in [django/db/backends/base/creation.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2b688b966f5d30414899549412d370e1317ddb8/django/db/backends/base/creation.py#L50)
- the code that creates the test database is in [django/test/utils.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2b688b966f5d30414899549412d370e1317ddb8/django/test/utils.py#L203)

and [creation.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/base/creation.py#L65) rewrites `settings.DATABASES[self.connection.alias]["NAME"]`, presumably so that future connections to it will connect to the new DB.